# AngularJS : Using $watch on two directive properties and keeping track of the oldValue and newValue of each?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a directive like this:

```
.directive('stuff', function(){
  return{
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
       name: '=',
       otherName: '='
     },
     controller: 'myCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
     link: function(scope, el, attr){
       //Stuff goes here
     }
  }
}
```

I am trying to run a `$watch` on the `name` and `otherName` attributes, and I need to be able to keep track of the `oldValue` and `newValue` of each.  This is how I've written my $watch in my link function:

```
scope.$watchCollection('[name, otherName]', function(newValue, oldValue){
  //Do stuff -- newValue[0] is the new value of name, newValue[1] is the new value for otherName, etc
}
```

For some reason, `oldValue` and `newValue` are always the same.  I know that they are supposed to be the same initially, and I have an if-statement that takes this into account.  But they are always the same even after I've triggered the watch multiple times.  When I logged the `oldValue` and `newValue` for one of the attributes, I found that both the `oldValue` and `newValue` have their values set to the new value after a change has been made.  For example, if I change the value of `name` from "bob" to "joe", both `oldValue[0]` and `newValue[0]` are set to `joe`.

What do I need to do so that the `oldValue` of `name` is the value of `name` before the most recent change, and the `oldValue` of `otherName` is the value of `otherName` before the most recent change?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you replicate it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/B9q3P1hCyxYgpQJjOxiR?p=preview

Comment: please add the html usage of your directive.  here is plunkr showing that your watch function works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/xAt1UPzLpKmAnl3iRfJb?p=preview